# Resume camera when i come back to app in wp8?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, css, windows-phone-7

I am windows phone 8 app developer, My question is how to resume camera? Basically camera is first page of my app and when i switch to some other functionality in the phone and when i come back to the app then camera page got black.

Comment: is it a PhotoCamera object or or a CameraCaptureTask?

Comment: Its PhotoCamera object.

Comment: Adding the rest in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I also came across the same problem in one of my Applications and this problem occurs because the instance of the photocamera object don't get flushed properly and that improper object is reassigned to the video brush which makes the things go to an unexpected way.

What best you can do to conquer the problem is

rewrite the OnNavigatedTo event wit these lines of code.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
       if (myCamera != null) // myCamera=PhotoCamera Object
                {
                   //Unsubscribing the events
                    myCamera.AutoFocusCompleted -= OnCameraAutoFocusCompleted;
                    myCamera.Initialized -= myCamera_Initialized;
                    myCamera.CaptureCompleted -= new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(camera_CaptureCompleted);
                    myCamera.CaptureImageAvailable -= new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs>(camera_CaptureImageAvailable);
                }

                viewfinderBrush = null;//viewfinderBrush =VideoBrush Onject
                canvasCameraView.Background = null; //canvasCameraView=Canvas Control I Used
                myCamera = null;
                viewfinderBrush = new VideoBrush();
                CompositeTransform ct = new CompositeTransform();
                ct.CenterX = .5;
                ct.CenterY = .5;
                ct.Rotation = 90;
                viewfinderBrush.RelativeTransform = ct;
                canvasCameraView.Background = viewfinderBrush;
                myCamera = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
                viewfinderBrush.SetSource(myCamera);
                myCamera.Initialized += myCamera_Initialized;
                myCamera.CaptureCompleted += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(camera_CaptureCompleted);
                myCamera.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs>(camera_CaptureImageAvailable);
 }
```

And this is the xaml

```
        <Canvas.Background>
        <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush">
            <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="viewfinderBrushTransform" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" Rotation="90" />
            </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </VideoBrush>
       </Canvas.Background>
                <StackPanel Name="stkLoading" Height="50" Canvas.Top="245" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Scanning.." HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Width="480"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
```

I Hope it helps

Comment: My Pleasure, All the best :)